# How to retrieve value based on Span value in JMeter with JQuery Extractor

Tags: jmeter

Trying to retrieve the componentId as a variable from the response below using the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter.

I'm successfully getting the componentId returned using

```
Expression: div#tab2-WidgetList span[componentType="portlet.application.widgets.monitorproxy"]  
Attribute: componentId
```

I could specify Match No. = 1 to return the first and Match No. = 2 to return the second, but I want to avoid hard coding it in case the order changes in the future.

I would like to return the value based off of the span elements of Test1 and Test2.

```html
    <li class="tab">
        <table id="tab2" class="tabTable tabTableSelected" cellpadding="0" onmousedown="tab.Console.openView('tab2', 'NONE', 'NONE', true, false, '');">
            <tr>
                <td class="tabLeft">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="tabCenter">
                    <span class="tabIconSpan"><img class="primaryTabIcon" src="/test/css/icons_24/Window View Large Icons.png"></span>
                    <span id="tab2Label" class="tabLabel">Dashboard</span>
                </td>
                <td class="tabRight">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="tab2-WidgetList" class="tabMenu">
                <span componentId="1234" componentType="portlet.application.widgets.monitorproxy" iconSource="/tabTest/css/icons_16/User1.png">Test1</span>
                <span componentId="9876" componentType="portlet.application.widgets.monitorproxy" iconSource="/tabTest/css/icons_16/User2.png">Test2</span>
        </div>
    </li>
```

JMeter is still pretty new to me, so I've been having some trouble getting this one down.

Comment: why don't you just use `div#tab2-WidgetList span[iconSource ="/tabTest/css/icons_16/User2.png"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select text value using CSS so I would recommend going for [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

The relevant XPath query will be something like:

```
//span[text()='Test1']/@componentId
```

Reference material:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. XPath allowed me to get the value I was looking for with minimal hoops to jump through. What I ended up with was `//div/span[text()='Test1']/@*[3]`. Not sure why, but I wasn't able to extract the attributes by name.